# merging .csv files with different number of variables in R

Tags: r, csv, for-loop, rbind

I have an R code which takes a set of .csv files and put all of them together.

```
files <- list.files()
for(i in 1:length(files)) assign(files[i], read.csv(files[i],header=F,stringsAsFactors=F,na.strings=c("", "NA")))

descript <- get(files[1])[1,][!is.na(get(files[1])[1,])]
variables <- get(files[1])[3,][!is.na(get(files[1])[3,])]
colNum <- length(variables)+length(descript)

## initialize dataframe
d <- get(files[1])
d <- d[-c(1:3),]
colnames(d) <- variables

jd <- data.frame(get(files[1])[2,])
colnames(jd) <- descript

d[,descript] <- jd[1,descript]

#  ## combine all
for(i in 2:length(files)){

  j <- get(files[i])
  j <- j[-c(1:3),]
  colnames(j) <- variables

  jd <- data.frame(get(files[i])[2,])
  colnames(jd) <- descript

  j[,descript] <- jd[1,descript]

  d <- rbind(d,j, fill = TRUE)
}
```

The structure of each .csv file is as follows: first row represents the name of some descriptive information about the session (e.g.,  recording date, etc). Second row: the values in each of these variables. The third row is empty. Fourth row, the name of the different variables of the experiment (e.g., condition, response, etc). From row 5 to the end, I have the values for each of these variables. My code works well, when the different .csv files have the same number of variables in the descriptive information part (first and second rows) or in the experiment variables (from row 4 to the end). The problem is that some files have different number of variables either in the descriptive or in the experimental part.

As you can see in my code, I have tried using `rbind(d,j, fill = TRUE), but I still get this error in the for loop part:

```
Error in names(x) <- value : 
  'names' attribute [45] must be the same length as the vector [28]
```

Comment: * Please provide sample data and in a [minimal and reproducible way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391). Otherwise people won't be able to test.

* Please show the expected output explicitly - what to do with the difference? Discard, keep, rename, overwrite or else?

Comment: Not sure of the actual file format (a sample would be good), but if it's yaml-like then https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/csvy might be useful?

Comment: Either way, I've done this before on several other questions (no links atm) here on SO, so it's likely fairly straight-forward to do given a sample or two and clear "instructions" of the expected format (blank lines, etc)

Comment: BTW: iteratively adding rows to a frame using `rbind(old, newrow)` works in practice but scales *horribly*, see "Growing Objects" in [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). For each row added, it makes a complete copy of all rows in `old`, which works but starts to slow down a lot. It is far better to produce a list of these new rows and then `rbind` them at one time; e.g., `out <- list(); for (...) { out <- c(out, list(newrow)); }; alldat <- do.call(rbind, out);`.

Comment: rbind requires the two data frames to have the same number of variables. but bind_rows from dplyr has different behavior